# Is there a file that can be used to monitor `/dev/sda`s only IO activity in Linux?

Tags: io

I am familiar with iotop and those tools. But for some strange reason I have to write a Ruby program on my own to monitor only read and write activity of all the partitions on /dev/sda). I want to know how does iotop work.

I have the Kernel `4.20.13-arch1-1-ARCH`

Is there a file that I can read with Ruby's IO.read('somefile') and do some formatting to get the IO details?

For further info, I want to know how does gnome-system-monitor monitor disk IO activities as a non-root user?

Comment: Look at `/proc/diskstats`

Comment: I just cat /proc/diskstats in a while loop, and I just wrote 1 GiB to the /dev/sda2, and saw the cat output to stdout changes. I think it works, but I don't get the meaning of the outputs. Any documentation?

Comment: Nice, I got it:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats

Comment: I recommend you read source of them.  I think `gnome-system-monitor` uses `gvfs`: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs